# How to disable UAC prompt using manifest file option in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, manifest, class-library, autoit

I want to execute autoit script using vb.net in vs 2010. While executing it keeps prompting. Is it possible to embed a manifest file in a class lib type project in vb.net. As currently I cant see any option to add a manifest. Or plz any other suggestions to disable that prompt to occur while executing a script from code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force C# App to run as administrator on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

Comment: Why does the prompt occur? Does the script require admin permissions? Remember that the latest beta of AutoIt is not digitally signed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop the prompt if you have UAC enabled and the script requires elevation to perform some task.

You can **force** the script to run elevated by doing something like the following:

```
 Dim proc As New ProcessStartInfo
    With proc
        .FileName = "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" 'replace with your script name
        If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then ' Windows Vista or higher
            .Verb = "runas"
        Else
            ' No need to prompt to run as admin
        End If
        Process.Start(proc)
 End With
```

Your only other option is to turn UAC off